# Viewing unused images in Strapi

Tags: image, optimization, strapi

I have users who add images to a Strapi Media Library.  I can't tell if images are actively used or not.  I would love to clean out images taking up space that aren't being used.  Is there a way to tell which images are used on the site and which images aren't?

Answer (score 1):

in images objects in strapi there is a field "related".
it's an array of data that uses the file. returns undefined if not used.
if you can't see the "related" field populate your request.